# How exactly does from...import... work?

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have a module `test.py` as follows:

```
def a():
    return "Hey!"

def b():
    return a()
```

In another module, I imported the function `b` as follows:

```
from test import b
```

Now, when I `print b()` in the second module, I get `Hey!` as the output. But considering that I only imported the function `b` and not `a`, I expected a NameError.

Does the `from x import y` statement automatically import all dependent functions and variables of `y` from `x`?

Comment: The only difference between the two statements is what name is bound; import test binds the name test to the module (Example so test -> test.modules['test']), while from test import 'b' binds a different name, b, pointing straight at the attribute contained inside of the module (Example so b -> test.modules['test'].b). The rest of the test module is still there,   check this link      [Check This Link](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function/187471)

Answer (score 0):

```
from test import b
```

This does not import any function other than `b` from `test`. It just makes the function `b()` available to your current module. But if you use

`import test`

then all the functions from `test` will be accessible to you. So now, you can call any function from `test` into your current module.

The best method is to use `globals()` within your current module. In first case (i.e. `from test import b`), `globals()` will show the function `b` from module `test`, which means you have access to **ONLY** `b` method from `test`.

But, in the later one (i.e. `import test`),  `globals()` will show module `test` itself, instead of function `b`. Thus you have access to the whole module `test` and all it's methods.

You might find [this blog](https://pabitrap.wordpress.com/2016/07/21/difference-between-from-module-import-function-and-import-module-in-python/) helpful.